# How to get One object value from database in Django

Tags: html, django, database, orm

The situation is I have a table named Status consists of two fields. one is id which is primary key and based on auto increment and second is status which is integer. Now, the scenario is that I only want to get the value of status not id.
Here are the details:

views.py:

```
from cvs.models import status_mod
```

```
field_object = status_mod.objects.get(status)
print(field_object)
```

models.py:

```
class status_mod(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField
  status = models.BigIntegerField

  class Meta:
    db_table = "status"
```

The issue is that I want to store status value in a variable and want to call him in my template.
Any solvable solution please

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the status value you want

```
field_object = status_mod.objects.get(status=1)
```

django already creates the id field by default, you don't need to create it

Comment: Dear @Teixeira It is giving me the error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'status' into field. Choices are: id

Comment: can you see if the status field was created in your db? @AHSANYAZDANI

Comment: yes, it is created:
status int(11) default value = none

Comment: Try to add parentheses like this status = models.BigIntegerField() and do the migrate commands, I replicated here and it works @AHSANYAZDANI

Comment: I did as you said, but It is giving me error:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'active'

Comment: yep, I edited my answer, change 'active' to 1

Comment: and what does mean by 1?

Comment: dear @Teixeira, table status have dynamic values, hope it will not contain the default value 1. I want dynamic latest value

Comment: @AHSANYAZDANI, it is a exemple, you need to create a new object first with status=1,
status_mod.objects.create(status=1)